# TextView with Html.fromHtml format issue

Tags: android, html, textview

I've a TextView that will receive some html formatted text like:

```
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"><strong>Name</strong>&nbsp; Mr. A</span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"><strong>Place:</strong>&nbsp; Somewhere over the rainbow...</span></p>
```

I'm using this code:

```
CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(html);
SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
text.setText(strBuilder);
```

Ended up with:

> Name: Mr. A\n\nPlace: Somewhere over the rainbow\n\n

Problem, I don't want "\n\n" I just want one "\n", so I've done this:

```
sequence = sequence.toString().replaceAll("\n\n", "\n");
```

Ended up with:

> Name: Mr. A\nPlace: Somewhere over the rainbow\n

And to remove the last "\n":

```
try {
    int i = sequence.toString().lastIndexOf("\n");
    sequence = new StringBuilder(sequence).replace(i, i + 1, "").toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ended up with:

> Name: Mr. A\nPlace: Somewhere over the rainbow

Perfect just like I wanted, but now all the HTML format is gone.
How can I solve this situation?
Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**
User **Bas van Stein** suggested I should remove `StringBuilder`, but I didn't post all the code. So, I use a `StringBuilder` because if the text contains an `URL` I do something like this (complete code):

```
CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(html);
sequence = sequence.toString().replaceAll("\n\n", "\n");
try {
    int i = sequence.toString().lastIndexOf("\n");
    sequence = new StringBuilder(sequence).replace(i, i + 1, "").toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
URLSpan[] urls = strBuilder.getSpans(0, sequence.length(), URLSpan.class);
for (URLSpan span : urls) {
    makeLinkClickable(context, strBuilder, span, color);
}
text.setText(strBuilder);
```

makeLinkClickable method:

```
private void makeLinkClickable(final Context context, SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder, final URLSpan span, int color) {
    int start = strBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
    int end = strBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
    int flags = strBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);
    strBuilder.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            ...
        }
    }, start, end, flags);
    strBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    strBuilder.removeSpan(span);
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Ok so I figured out what is causing the loss of the format information, is the fact that I'm ignoring the `Spanned` text converted from `Html.fromHtml(html)`. I guess I'll have to remove the "\n\n" and the last "\n" without losing the `Spanned` object with all the `Span` styles, etc. Working on it...

Comment: I'd use `<br/>` to replace `\n`. Since you want HTML line breaks, in HTML code - not Java ones.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you use a `StringBuilder`, this is not needed at all. You can just set the text as html like this:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

So just remove the string builder and you should get what you want.

---

**EDIT** Ok, after your updated question, I have one more suggestion:
What happens when you replace the \n **before** you pass it to `Html.fromHtml()`.
Might work..

Comment: Yes I don't have to use a StringBuilder but the problem remains. I've updated my code. Thanks

Comment: Changed my answer, not sure if it will work, but I think your on the correct way already.